# I'm trying to find the average speed and wants the simplest way to do it using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to find the average speed in multiple inputs (in this case 2) in (meter/seconds) and (km/h) in the simplest way, instead of doing it in this way:

```
dist = float(input('Distance(m) : '))
time = float(input('Finish time(s) : '))
dist_2 = float(input('Distance(m) : '))
time_2 = float(input('Finish time(s) : '))

speed = (dist / time) 
speed_2 = (dist / time) * 3.6
average = (dist / time) + (dist_2 / time_2) / 2
average_2 = (dist / time) + (dist_2 / time_2) / 2 * 3.6

print('speed is(m/s) : ', round(speed, 3))
print('speed is(km/h) : ', round(speed_2, 3))
print('average is(m/s) : ', round(average, 3))
print('average is (km/h) : ', round(average_2, 3))
```

Is there any more simple way to do it? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Please make sure to accept the best answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

The input end is always going to be a bit clunky if you are looking user inputs

But after that, if you assembled lists it would be a lot easier using statistics.mean

Something like the below might be a bit nicer and more flexible:

```
import statistics

dists = []
times = []
speedsMS = []
nJourneys = int(input("How many journeys have been made?"))
for i in range(0, nJourneys):
    dists.append(input("What distance was journey " + str(i+1) + "?"))
    times.append(input("what time did journey " + str(i+1) + " take?"))
    speedsMS.append(dists[len(dists)-1]/times[len(times)-1])


averageSpeedMS = statistics.mean(speedsMS)
averageSpeedKMHr = averageSpeedMS * 3.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to eliminate the duplicate code and intermediate variables in reading the speed from user:

```
def speed():
  (dist, time) = [ float(input(q + ' : ')) for q in ('Distance(m)', 'Finish 
  return dist / time
```

Then write a function to generate the report given a tuple of speeds:

```
def report(speeds):
    for t in ('speed', lambda l: l[0]), ('average', lambda l: sum(l) / len(l)):
        for u in (('m/s', 1), ('km/h', 3.6)):
            print(f'{t[0]} is({u[0]}) : ', round(t[1](speeds) * u[1], 3))
```

and drive it with:

```
report((speed(), speed()))
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked and I just wanted to ask you what does the code 'print(f'{t[0]} is({u[0]}) : ', round(t[1](speeds) * u[1], 3))' mean?

Comment: `f''`is a format string which evaluate the variables inside `{}`. `t` for type is the variable of the outer loop.  It iterates over a tuple with two elements.  Each element is a string and a function.  `u` for unit is the variable of the inner loop which also a tuple with two elements.  Each element consist of a string of the unit and a factor.

Comment: It looks complicated but the trick to come up with this is very general.  Compare the 4 lines, anything that is identical you carry through to the print statement exactly as is.  Anything that is different you place with a variable or a function call depending if it's a value or behavior (calculation).